# xAxis problems with Highstock

Tags: highcharts

We are working with Highstock to create dynamic charts.

Here is the xAxis configuration (full code in the jsfiddle):

```
    "xAxis": [{
      "lineColor": "Black",
      "tickColor": "Black",
      "gridLineColor": "transparent",
      "gridLineDashStyle": "Solid",
      "type": "datetime",
      "lineWidth": 1,
      "tickLength": 5,
      "tickWidth": 1,
      "gridLineWidth": 1,
      "opposite": false,
      "startOnTick": false,
      "endOnTick": false,
      "labels": {
        "style": {
          "color": "Black",
          "fontFamily": "verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif",
          "fontSize": 8.1000000000000014
        },
        "align": "center"
      },
      "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
        "hour": "%H:%M",
        "day": "%d/%m",
        "week": "%d/%m",
        "month": "%m/%y",
        "year": "%Y"
      }
    }]
```

It seems there is a problem with the xAxis going out of the curve bounds. As seen here, the 10:30 is outside: 
https://jsfiddle.net/chrilith/5nv9pg33/

If you remove half of the data (starting at line 68) you'll notice erratic ticks on X too.

Also, with more data, sometimes, the last label is over the previous one.

It seems that we've missed some configuration here. Tested a lot options with not luck.

Anyway clue on how to fix these all?

Thanks!

Comment: The reason of that is using column, which has a pointRange and paddings. As a result this space is added after last column, so your area chart has this as well. The solution is using to separated xAxis, firt per are and second per column serie.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the 2 areas are related to the same thing and must be aligned (it is just 2 different variables). With 2 axes, ticks won't be aligned. Also, the last point isn't outside of the curve area, so I really don't see why a tick is rendered outside of it (pointRange and padding aren't so big).